# What is the time complexity of a binary multiplication using Karatsuba Algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, time-complexity, arithmetic

My apologies if the question sounds naive, but I'm trying wrap my head around the idea of time complexity.

In general, the Karatsuba Multiplication is said to have a time complexity of `O(n^1.5...)`.
The algorithm assumes that the addition and subtraction take about `O(1)` each. However, for binary addition and subtraction, I don't think it will be `O(1)`. If I'm not mistaken, a typical addition or subtraction of two binary numbers takes `O(n)` time.

What will be the total time complexity of the following program then that multiplies two binary numbers using **Karatsuba Algo** that in turn performs binary addition and subtraction?

```
long multKaratsuba(long num1, long num2) {
 if ((num1>=0 && num1<=1) && (num2>=0 && num2<=1)) {
   return num1*num2;
 }

 int length1 = String.valueOf(num1).length(); //takes O(n)? Not sure
 int length2 = String.valueOf(num2).length(); //takes O(n)? Not sure

 int max = length1 > length2 ? length1 : length2;
 int halfMax = max/2;

 // x = xHigh + xLow
 long num1High = findHigh(num1, halfMax); // takes O(1)
 long num1Low = findLow(num1, halfMax); // takes O(1)

 // y = yHigh + yLow 
 long num2High = findHigh(num2, halfMax); // takes O(1)
 long num2Low = findLow(num2, halfMax); // takes O(1)

 // a = (xHigh*yHigh)
 long a = multKaratsuba(num1High, num2High);

 // b = (xLow*yLow)
 long b = multKaratsuba(num1Low, num2Low);

 //c = (xHigh + xLow)*(yHigh + yLow) - (a + b);
 long cX = add(xHigh,xLow); // this ideally takes O(n) time
 long cY = add(yHigh,yLow); // this ideally takes O(n) time
 long cXY = multKaratsuba(cX, cY);
 long cAB = add(a, b) // this ideally takes O(n) time
 long c = subtract(cXY, cAB) // this ideally takes O(n) time

 // res = a*(10^(2*m)) + c*(10^m) + b
 long resA = a * (long) Math.pow(10, (2*halfMax)); // takes O(1)
 long resC = c * (long) Math.pow(10, halfMax); // takes O(1)
 long resAC = add(resA, resC); // takes O(n)
 long res = add(resAC, b); // takes O(n)

 return res;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mistaken.
The analysis of the Karatsuba algorithm takes addition and subtraction into account.

If you analyze your pseudo-code, you can see that you have exactly 3 recursive function calls with arguments of size $n/2$, and all other operations like addition, subtraction, extracting the higher and lower bits, ...,  run in $O(n)$.

Therefore you get the recursion $T(n) = 3 \cdot T(n/2) + O(n)$ for the complexity, which gives the following according to the Master theorem: $$T(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_2 3}) = \Theta(n^{1.58...})$$

---

Fun fact: even if you assume that all the bitwise operations (addition, subtraction, ...) take $O(1)$, the code will still have the same complexity.
Since the number of calls to the three subproblems dominates the other work. But I doubt, that any book/lecturer would assume that the bitwise operations are constant, since the whole point of the algorithm is that you want to multiply large numbers.

---

Btw, you have some small errors in your pseudo-code/analyze.
E.g. here:

```
long resA = a * (long) Math.pow(10, (2*halfMax)); // takes O(1)
```

You want to multiply with a power of 2, to make it efficient (since you are working with binary numbers). And even corrected it will not run in $O(1)$, because you need to copy/move $O(n)$ bits. So this line will also run in $O(n)$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the errors. Explanation makes sense